# How can I match a Pandas Dataframe with invalid characters (accents) to an array?

Tags: python, pandas, utf-8, ascii

I have been trying to use a Pandas Dataframe  in Python 3 to find a specific id matching a name from a CSV file. The API I am reading from gives me the name António, along with other names, the way I need it to with the accent in a column called "first". I have an array of names that won't necessarily have all of the accents I need to match. This program seems to work for every name I try except for the ones that have different values for accented characters.

```
import pandas as pd

nameArray=[Antonio,Matt,Mark,Raul]
playersUrl = 'https://www.FakeSite.com/players'
playerData = pd.read_csv(playersUrl, names=["PLAYERID", "FIRSTNAME"]

for first, playerid in zip(playerData["FIRSTNAME"],playerData["PLAYERID"]):
    for i in len(nameArray):
        testName = nameArray[i]    
        if first == testName:
            return playerid
```

Comment: Your indenting has some challenges.

Comment: Are you saying you want to match names with or without accents?

Comment: The playerData dataframe from the CSV has accented words. The array is filled with unaccented words, and I need them to match.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do a compare without diacritics, see previous SO post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517923/what-is-the-best-way-to-remove-accents-in-a-python-unicode-string):

> [Unidecode](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Unidecode) is the correct answer for this. It transliterates any unicode string into the closest possible representation in ascii text.